# Ubuntu apt-get and COTURN

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, turn

Hi I have been trying to download COTURN server on my Ubuntu installation. I am following this link https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#coturn

But I am getting this error while running `apt-get install`

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your ubuntu/debian apt repository

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

or refresh it with..

```
apt-get update
```